# How to get Main Window in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have got some generic `User Control` under the `Canvas` of the WPF window.

How do I can get that window?

I used this approach

```
void UserControlMethod()
{    
   WindowInteropHelper WindowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper((Window)((Grid)(((Canvas)this.Parent).Parent)).Parent);    
}
```

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use: [`Window.GetWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx).

The `WindowInteropHelper` is for interacting with native windows code or API's so that's definitely not what you want.

Comment: Got it. It should be WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(Window.GetWindow(this));

Comment: Are you doing some Win32 API calls or something?